# Recreation data for Ontario (Canada)?

Tags: data, canada

I am aware that a similar question has been asked as [Sites with recreational shapefiles for United States?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17902/sites-with-recreational-shapefiles-for-united-states) but I am looking for comprehensive sources of recreational data (specifically for the province of Ontario, Canada).

Land Information Ontario has some data (**I have everything they can provide**), but I am looking for something covering more categories (and fairly current if possible).

I'm hoping to find golf courses, campgrounds, hiking/biking trails, kayaking/canoeing routes and other data of this nature.

Other categories are welcome if you have any suggestions.

Comment: If you are looking for data, you may want to post your question at [Open Data SE (beta)](http://opendata.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Many of these (3 of the 4) can be found in open street map. Here is some good information on obtaining the data

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

and here is some info on converting it to shapefile.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles

Comment: Thank you your suggestion.  I will definitely be looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good website which allows you to download shapefiles with various aspects such as admin areas, roads, population densities etc.

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Comment: Hey.  I followed the link you posted.  I don't see any recreational categories.  There o nly seems to be the standard things such as Lakes, rivers, roads, etc, etc.